# Pure CSS hover menu

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make an **basic, preferrably no javascript, hover drop down menu** for a navigational bar and it appears when it is hovered over, except it disappears when you scroll off of it. I have experimented with it and can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div tabindex="0" class="locations-menu" id="home-menu">
    <div class="arrow">
    </div>

    <ul class="locations-menu-content" id="locations-header">
        <br>
        <a class="button" href="location1.html">Location #1</a><br>
        <a class="button" href="location2.html">Location #2</a><br>         
        <a class="button" href="location3.html">Location #3</a><br>


</ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button {
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#3D3D3D;
}

.arrow {
    top:140%;
    background-color:#648FBD;
    position:absolute;
    height:50%;
    width:30%;
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.locations-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height:50px;
    top:3%;
    left:30%;
}

.locations-menu:before {
    content: "Locations";
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
    font-size:24px;
}

.locations-menu:focus {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.locations-menu:hover .arrow {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility 2s;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.locations-menu-content:hover .locations-menu-content {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events:auto;
}

.locations-menu:hover .locations-menu-content {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility 2s;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.locations-menu-content {
    background-color:#648FBD;
    top:125%;
    left:-15%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width:200%;
    height:200%;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index:2;
}
```

If someone would be willing to fix the code or atleast tell me what is wrong that would be nice. There is probably a simple solution to this but I again, can't seem to find it.

For those who like to see the code in action, **here is the** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShaunLoftin/356tLLfc/).

Thank you.

Comment: Note that this is not the way to make a proper listed menu. Use list items `li` and put your links `a` in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap your content in a container and set `height: 100%`. That way the hover action takes the entire height but the content is positioned where you want it.

**HTML**

```
<div tabindex="0" class="locations-menu" id="home-menu">    
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="arrow"></div>
      <ul class="locations-menu-content" id="locations-header">
         <br/>
         <a class="button" href="location1.html">Location #1</a><br/>
         <a class="button" href="location2.html">Location #2</a><br/>           
         <a class="button" href="location3.html">Location #3</a><br/>           
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
   height: 100%;  
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/356tLLfc/2/)

Comment: Thanks, it looks perfect. I don't quite know who the downvote was but I am kinda new to S.O. so I can't upvote it yet, ha. But thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

One quick fix is to add some negative `margin-top` to the elements that create the bubble element(`.locations-menu-content` and `.arrow`):

```css
.button {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3D3D3D;
}
.arrow {
  top: 140%;
  background-color: #648FBD;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: -40px;
}
.locations-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  top: 3%;
  left: 30%;
}
.locations-menu:before {
  content: "Locations";
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-size: 24px;
}
.locations-menu:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.locations-menu:hover .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 2s;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.locations-menu-content:hover .locations-menu-content {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.locations-menu:hover .locations-menu-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 2s;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.locations-menu-content {
  background-color: #648FBD;
  top: 125%;
  left: -15%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: -24px;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="locations-menu" id="home-menu">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <ul class="locations-menu-content" id="locations-header">
    <br> <a class="button" href="location1.html">Location #1</a>
    <br> <a class="button" href="location2.html">Location #2</a>
    <br> <a class="button" href="location3.html">Location #3</a>
    <br>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works cleanly except is there any way to keep it the same distance away from the regular menu tab. With the margins it **overlaps** the word locations (in my Google Chrome atleast).